# Error while running command npm run serve

Tags: node.js

When i am starting my server using npm run serve. I am getting this error as:

> > serverCodenode_modules/file-system/vendor/util.js:34 [1]       target[key] = value; [1]                   ^ [1]  [1] TypeError:
> > Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'isExternal') [1]     at
> > extend (serverCode/node_modules/file-system/vendor/util.js:34:19) [1]
> > at extend (serverCode/node_modules/file-system/vendor/util.js:32:7)
> > [1]     at Object.
> > (serverCode/node_modules/file-system/vendor/util.js:41:1) [1]     at
> > Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14) [1]     at
> > Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10) [1]
> > at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) [1]     at
> > Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) [1]     at
> > Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) [1]     at
> > require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18) [1]     at
> > Object. (serverCode/node_modules/file-system/index.js:6:12)

Comment: Please add more context. What is `npm run serve`?

Comment: npm run serve is a command which is added in package.json to start the node application on a default port to serve a client request.

Comment: Thank you @Moti for your response. The issue got resolved by reinstalling file-system node package using command npm install file-system. The issue persist if i use command npm install file-system --save or if I fix the vulnerability by npm audit fix. Can you please clarify on this.

Comment: I would be happy to help but it is still too little information. Please update the original question, add your `package.json` for starters